# Softserial.println slow down loop for PPM interups

Tags: c, arduino

I have tried to write PPM values reader which sends by bluetooth using softserial library. PPM reader works good until adding `BTSerial.println(value1);`

```
#include <PPMReader.h>
#include <InterruptHandler.h> 
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int interruptPin = 3;
int channelAmount = 2;
int pwmOutPin = 2;


PPMReader ppm(interruptPin, channelAmount);
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(8,9);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);  
  BTSerial.write("AT\r\n");
  BTSerial.write("AT\r\n");
  BTSerial.write("AT+INQ\r\n");
  delay(5000);
  BTSerial.write("AT+CONN1\r\n");

  Serial.println("Started");
}

void loop()
{

  unsigned int value1 = ppm.latestValidChannelValue(1, 0);

  BTSerial.println(value1);
  Serial.println("value1: " + String(value1));

}
```

without `BTSerial.println` values are:

```
1500
1500
1500
1498
1500
etc...
```

with  `BTSerial.println` values are:

```
1500
1304
1500
1076
1848
```

The most correct value is stable `1500`

What do I do bad? Can I optimize performance of this? Board is Arduino Nano V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial print can significantly slow down program execution on small MCU. SoftwareSerial is very resource hungry. The best approach is not to use it. Get an Arduino Mega-based board which has four hardware serial peripherals. Alternatively, output your diagnostic into SPI/I2C and read the output via logic analyzer.

If you can't do any of the above, try to increase `Serial` data rate.

Comment: Can I use hardware serial Rx/Tx of nano board? Mega is too large for me.

Comment: This is the best way, yes. I was assuming you have it reserved for something else.

Comment: It somehow connected with usb I think.

Comment: This is correct. When you plug it to a USB port on a PC you'll get a serial peripheral, called `/dev/ttyUSBn` on Linux. You use it to program your board from the IDE. You can use the same port for serial io, using built-in IDE terminal, or any other.